# Laravel-Authentication: Passport vs Sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, sanctum

I am new to Laravel and for practicing I am trying to create a website like GoFundMe but simpler with Laravel and Vue js.
But am very confused with Laravel's authentication systems, even though I have read most of the questions here.

Which authentication system should I use ? is it ok to use Sanctum for authentication and then Spatie for user permissions?

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a section for [Passport Or Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#passport-or-sanctum) which provides a succinct explanation of which package is appropriate in certain circumstances. The Spatie permissions package is totally separate from, and usable with, both Sanctum and Passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a clear concept of the topic `authentication` & `authorization` first. You may use Laravel `Sanctum` powered by Laravel framework as well. Because it provides authentication support for SPAs (single-page applications), mobile applications, and simple, token-based APIs. You may also have a look at `passport` later.

After passing your authentication, the topic `authorization` comes. You may use `Gate`. But as you are new to Laravel framework, then it seems to be a good choice to use `laravel spatie` for managing your permissions. But keep in mind that, it uses `Gate` concept under the hood.